# set Environment variable as cookie (apache)

Tags: apache, cookies

i am trying to set the cookies value to a environment variable. Which is a country code. Part of the configuration as below.

```
MaxMindDBEnable On
MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /etc/apache2/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE COUNTRY_DB/country/iso_code
```

Want to set the cookie name "CC" value to "MM_COUNTRY_CODE" from above.
i have tried the below but getting a NULL.

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "cccookie=([^;]+)" MM_COUNTRY_CODE=$1
Header set Set-Cookie "CC=%{CCCOOKIE}e;path=/;Expires=MI3600" env=MM_COUNTRY_CODE
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/541458/how-do-you-use-apache-setenvif-with-cookie-values - take a look and see if that has your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace below lines

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "cccookie=([^;]+)" MM_COUNTRY_CODE=$1
Header set Set-Cookie "CC=%{CCCOOKIE}e;path=/;Expires=MI3600" env=MM_COUNTRY_CODE
```

with this below line

Header **add** set Set-Cookie "CC=%{MM_COUNTRY_CODE}e"

'%{MM_COUNTRY_CODE}e' The contents of the environment variable MM_COUNTRY_CODE.notice the 'e'.